# Slow boot! Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, server, dmesg

Not sure why suddenly a very slow boot when I start Ubuntu. Now it is about 3 mins to boot fully. The dmesg:

```
[    6.446195] audit: type=1400 audit(1481821642.925:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/clamd" pid=794 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Then the next line:

```
[   94.175197] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
```

So obviously here is the problem. Not sure how to fix. help?

Comment: It seems you found only half the problem. 88 seconds pass between the two lines (which is enormous), but you say the boot takes about 180 seconds, so you also need to find where the other 100 seconds went. Can you run `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame` or copy the output in your question?

Comment: Hi Adrien, no, this is the only problem lines. When I say 3 minutes, it feels like it sometimes.

Comment: I know this is old, but you need more than these two lines of output for help, they don't point to anything specific.  `dmesg`, `systemd-analyze` would be good starts.  If you are still getting it. :)

Comment: This I found super helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086858/ubuntu-18-04-slow-boot-time